# Can I create my own Installer using Visual Basic 2015?

Tags: java, visual-studio-2015, installation

I am building my own Java program Java being an interpreted language does not have the ability to run as an executable moreover any jar file can be decompiled using any of the free decompilers to their source code.

My question is Can I create my own Installer using Visual Basic 2015 such that the User does not become aware they are going to run a Java program?

My choice for Visual Basic is because it is really a RAD for GUI based windows apps. Although Java is OS agnostic my program in Java is going to run by users on Windows as they use this OS.

May thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your question revolves around the fact that you want to create your own installer.

Yes Visual Basic is a RAD GUI and does the work very fast. It is faster to make any application than in c# or VC++. So your choice of VB is good.

If you looking for an alternative to making your own installer in Visual Basic then you should consider InnoSetup which allows you to customize your Installer steps completely including distributing your version of JVM bundled inside the Install pack.

the best part is it is free and can be downloaded from [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

Comment: I am also looking for hiding the jar files which are being run by the Java program while installing them is it possible for the user not to know if any jars are running?

Comment: These are two different things @richgems the first one is to create your own installer the second to hide the fact that you are transferring jar files. Why do you want to hide jar files from users? they can always go inside your directories and find out this program runs on Jar java

Comment: My executable is made in C# which calls the java program and then it creates the JVM at runtime and makes the java program run let us assume my installer files are *.hidden and then at runtime I make them *.jar and then after the run time is over again make them to *.hidden so where will the user come to know about the jar file?

Comment: Yes this would work for C# code and yes you can bundle your entire JVM without the need to install it on the target user machine with InnoSetup this solution does not work with MSI based installers as they have the limitation to embed only native code. Innosetup is customizable and lets you embed any type of files that you want.

Comment: I tried Innosetup last night and was able to create a custom install and it worked on a vanilla machine it installed and worked fine. Thanks for understanding the full situation and explaining and answering me precisely/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an MSI-based installer project, then Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition has an add-in for an installer project:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects

Start here:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/

old but still works this way.

Comment: Does this MSI based solution let you install JAva jar file codes and the JVM bundle along with it. Have you tried it did it work? @PhilDW